# Why does the head of the NPA or L have to show themselves on TV just because the second Kira asked them to?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-note

In Episode 11 of *Death Note*, The second Kira seems to want to take the life of either the head of the NPA or L, simply by telling them to show themselves on TV.  What if they don’t show themselves on TV? Did the second Kira hold something over them that was not explicitly mentioned in the video tape? In the anime, it does not make sense; in the same episode, it is mentioned that the leaders of every nation pressured real L to be on TV.

Please note that I am not asking *how* the second Kira performed the kill in general. My question is: Why does the head of the NPA or L have to show themselves on TV, *just because the second Kira asked them to*?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you're asking here... If you're asking how the 2nd Kira can kill someone just by seeing them on TV; I can tell you that will be answered in following episodes, and it would be a spoiler to have that answered on here.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure I should answer that. Did you watch the entire series yet?

Comment: If it's unclear how do you know it will be answered in the next episode? @one who

Comment: @cde "**If** you're asking how the 2nd Kira can kill someone just by seeing them on TV"...

Comment: @onewho I have watched the entire series, so obviously I know how the second Kira could kill someone just by looking at his/her face. My question is: Why does the head of the NPA or L have to show themselves on TV just because the second Kira ask them to (as mentioned in the detail of the question)? I edited the question detail and the title to emphasize this point.

Comment: "(Please read the detail of the question!)" No need of this note in the title. People will read the body and try to answer the question. You need to make edits to the body to make the question clear not the title. Users will read the body.

Comment: @SS I think it depends on the person.

Comment: Regardless, adding meta notes in the title is frowned upon. If you feel you must put this in the title to make your question clear, your question *is not* clear. That said, I think your question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's an Or Else threat.

> So **I start by** taking the life of either the director general of the NPA or the detective known as L, who's currently leading the investigation against me.
>
> The director general or L, who [would pay] the price for your refusal to cooperate in the creation of the peaceful world?

The 2nd Kira didn't specify a specific target of their threat, as they did not need to. They can kill anyone remotely, and that's enough of a threat.  Not just one person, but lots at the same time. They also held an entire TV station hostage with the same threat. Air these tapes when i tell you or you die. Magically.

Kira is threatening strangers' lives to force L or the police chief to appear on TV. They are also threatening L's life, which makes the police worry as he's the best bet at the moment in catching them.

It's a general threat to kill more people if they don't do what the 2nd Kira wants.